# WebApi Controller Unit Test not working for HttpResponseMessage

Tags: controller, asp.net-web-api2, xunit.net, httpresponsemessage

I actually haven't written any unit test in a while, maybe Im just out of the swing of things.  Im trying to test a HttpResponseMessage from a controller in my WebApi. I have no error, actually the test completes with a green check which I find strange because when I went to debug it to double check the assert I realized I wasn't ever hitting my assert.  Here is my test.

```
[Fact]
    public void TestDudeManController()
    {
        //arrange
        DudeManModel dmmRequest =  new DudeManModel();
        DudeManModel dmmResponse = new DudeManModel();
        HttpResponseMessage hrm = new HttpResponseMessage();
        dmmRequest.Name = "Test-Duder";
        dmmResponse.Name = "Hey " + dmmRequest.Name + ", Im The Dude man.";
        var dudeController = new DudeManController();        
        dudeController.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        dudeController.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();       

        //act
        hrm = dudeController.Dude(dmmRequest);

        //assert
        //Assert.Equal(4, 4);
        Assert.True(hrm.IsSuccessStatusCode);          

    }
```

Here is the controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("dude")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Dude([FromBody]DudeManModel name)
    {
        log.Info("WEBAPI POST INITIATED::NAME IS::" + name.Name);

        name.Name = "Hey " + name.Name + ", Im The Dude man.";
        name.Link = "dude.png";

       log.InfoFormat("WEBAPI POST UPDATED::NAME IS::{0}::PIC IS::{1}", name.Name, name.Link);

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, name);
    }
```

Basically I get to this line 'dudeController.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();' and that's it. Test is over.  Test is marked as passed.

This is a standard .Net Framework WebApi and Im using xUnit for testing. Any idea why my test bows out that line as a successful test, i'd really appreciate some help.  Im not finding much on it from my searches so far.

*****Disclaimer

Just in case anyone is wondering, there's nothing weird about this test controller.  The code itself is just an homage to the movie the The Big Lebowski.  He is and forever will be 'The Dude'.  But reading my code, it does look a little funny now that Im seeing it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is weird but I had my project set to Release in Visual Studio, I switched it to Debug and it works now, I'm getting to my assert.  Simple fix.  I'm not sure about the behavior regarding why, if anyone has anything to add please let me know.